# Using GULP to parse JSON and output the result to a HTML file

Tags: html, json, parsing, gulp

I'm trying to use GULP to parse a JSON file from a directory and write the result into a HTML file. Is that something feasible? If so please help me providing the links and examples to it.

Comment: How do you want to write the parsed result into a HTML file? Do you want to use some templates?

Comment: I have an array in json and i just want to write the contents of the array into a .html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to use gulp to write .json into HTML unless you have multiples files.

Try that :

- Read the json file with require
- Read the HTML file with fs.readFileSync;
- Create some HTML from the JSON
- Replace a custom string into the HTML with my HTML
- Write the file

json file :

```
[
  {
    "name":"Doe",
    "firstName":"John",
    "age":"35"
  },
  {
    "name":"Man",
    "firstName":"Bat",
    "age":"40"
  }
]
```

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      %CONTENT%
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var json = require('./myjsonFile.json');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./myhtmlFile.html', {encoding:'utf8'});

// create table HTML
// parse results and return each HTML lines
var parsedResults = json.map(function(item) {
  return '<tr>'
    + '<td>' + item.name + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + item.firstName + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + item.age + '</td>'
    + '</tr>'
})

var newHtml = html.replace('%CONTENT%', parsedResults.join('\n'));

fs.writeFileSync('my-new-file.html', newHtml, {encoding:'utf8'});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this excellent piece of example code. when i try to do the same i'm getting the below error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: Also i'm writing the piece of code inside a Gulp task so that i can make it run as part of the build process. here is the code,

Comment: var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');
var json = require('../../myjsonFile.json');

gulp.task('writeJSON', function(file, obj) {

 var parsedResults = json.results.map(function(item) {
   return item.name;
 });
 
 fs.writeFileSync('myhtmlFile.html', parsedResults.join('\n'), function (err) {
   
 });

});

Comment: Result is a little error in my code, juste use "json"

Comment: thank you. That worked. I love this example code as it served as a great help for my query. Thanks again.

Comment: It should be require('./myjsonFile.json'); or the file won't be found

Comment: I'm getting cannot find module 'myjsonFile.json' while running gulp...But i have the same file name in my folder